# DNBuilder Shinyapps: change term labels

Tags: r, shinyapps

Im building a shinyapp from a log regression using the DynNom::DNbuilder R package. I obtained the ui.R, server.R and global.R code and the app works. However, I'm trying to change the format of the sliders and the labels but I haven't been able to do so.
I'd appreciate if someone could shed some light here . Thanks!

Here's my model and the labels i would like the app to show:

```
data <- data.frame(
   x = c(0,1,0),
   y = c(3,6,2),
   z = c(1.3, 2.8, 3.1),
   w = c(1,0,0)
)

model <- lrm(x ~ y + z + w,   data = data)

modellabels <- c("ylabel", "zlabel", "wlabel")
```

Here's the DNbuilder code:

```
model <- lrm(x ~ y + z + w, data =data
DNbuilder(model, data = data, clevel = 0.95, m.summary = c("raw"), covariate = c("numeric"))
```

Here's what I got after running DNbuilder:

```
**ui.R**

ui = bootstrapPage(fluidPage(
  titlePanel('app'),


    sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(uiOutput('manySliders'),
                               uiOutput('setlimits'),
                               actionButton('add', 'Predict'),
                               br(), br(),
                               helpText('Press Quit to exit the application'),
                               actionButton('quit', 'Quit')
    ),
    mainPanel(tabsetPanel(id = 'tabs',
                          tabPanel('Graphical Summary', plotlyOutput('plot')),
                          tabPanel('Numerical Summary', verbatimTextOutput('data.pred')),
                          tabPanel('Model Summary', verbatimTextOutput('summary'))
    )
    )
    )))




----------
**server.R**

server = function(input, output){
observe({if (input$quit == 1)
          stopApp()})

limits <- reactive({ if (input$limits) { limits <- c(input$lxlim, input$uxlim) } else {
                         limits <- limits0 } })

output$manySliders <- renderUI({
  slide.bars <- list()
               for (j in 1:length(preds)){
               if (terms[j+1] == "factor"){
               slide.bars[[j]] <- list(selectInput(paste("pred", j, sep = ""), names(preds)[j], preds[[j]]$v.levels, multiple = FALSE))
               }
               if (terms[j+1] == "numeric"){
               if (covariate == "slider") {
               slide.bars[[j]] <- list(sliderInput(paste("pred", j, sep = ""), names(preds)[j],
               min = preds[[j]]$v.min, max = preds[[j]]$v.max, value = preds[[j]]$v.mean))
               }
               if (covariate == "numeric") {
               slide.bars[[j]] <- list(numericInput(paste("pred", j, sep = ""), names(preds)[j], value = zapsmall(preds[[j]]$v.mean, digits = 4)))
               }}}
               do.call(tagList, slide.bars)
})

output$setlimits <- renderUI({
        if (is.null(DNlimits)){
               setlim <- list(checkboxInput("limits", "Set x-axis ranges"),
               conditionalPanel(condition = "input.limits == true",
               numericInput("uxlim", "x-axis upper", zapsmall(limits0[2], digits = 2)),
               numericInput("lxlim", "x-axis lower", zapsmall(limits0[1], digits = 2))))
        } else{ setlim <- NULL }
        setlim
})

a <- 0
new.d <- reactive({
               input$add
               input.v <- vector("list", length(preds))
               for (i in 1:length(preds)) {
               input.v[[i]] <- isolate({
               input[[paste("pred", i, sep = "")]]
               })
               names(input.v)[i] <- names(preds)[i]
               }
               out <- data.frame(lapply(input.v, cbind))
               if (a == 0) {
               input.data <<- rbind(input.data, out)
               }
               if (a > 0) {
               if (!isTRUE(compare(old.d, out))) {
               input.data <<- rbind(input.data, out)
               }}
               a <<- a + 1
               out
})

p1 <- NULL
old.d <- NULL
data2 <- reactive({
               if (input$add == 0)
               return(NULL)
               if (input$add > 0) {
               if (!isTRUE(compare(old.d, new.d()))) {
               isolate({
               mpred <- getpred.DN(model, new.d(), set.rms=T)$pred
               se.pred <- getpred.DN(model, new.d(), set.rms=T)$SEpred
               if (is.na(se.pred)) {
               lwb <- "No standard errors"
               upb <- "by 'lrm'"
               pred <- mlinkF(mpred)
               d.p <- data.frame(Prediction = zapsmall(pred, digits = 3),
               Lower.bound = lwb, Upper.bound = upb)
               } else {
               lwb <- sort(mlinkF(mpred + cbind(1, -1) * (qnorm(1 - (1 - clevel)/2) * se.pred)))[1]
               upb <- sort(mlinkF(mpred + cbind(1, -1) * (qnorm(1 - (1 - clevel)/2) * se.pred)))[2]
               pred <- mlinkF(mpred)
               d.p <- data.frame(Prediction = zapsmall(pred, digits = 3),
               Lower.bound = zapsmall(lwb, digits = 3),
               Upper.bound = zapsmall(upb, digits = 3))
               }
               old.d <<- new.d()
               data.p <- cbind(d.p, counter = 1, count=0)
               p1 <<- rbind(p1, data.p)
               p1$counter <- seq(1, dim(p1)[1])
               p1$count <- 0:(dim(p1)[1]-1) %% 11 + 1
               p1
               })
               } else {
               p1$count <- seq(1, dim(p1)[1])
               }}
               rownames(p1) <- c()
               p1
})

output$plot <- renderPlotly({
  if (input$add == 0)
               return(NULL)
               if (is.null(new.d()))
               return(NULL)
               coll=c("#0E0000", "#0066CC", "#E41A1C", "#54A552", "#FF8000", "#BA55D3",
               "#006400", "#994C00", "#F781BF", "#00BFFF", "#A9A9A9")
               lim <- limits()
               yli <- c(0 - 0.5, 10 + 0.5)
               dat2 <- data2()
               if (dim(data2())[1] > 11){
               input.data = input.data[-c(1:(dim(input.data)[1]-11)),]
               dat2 <- data2()[-c(1:(dim(data2())[1]-11)),]
               yli <- c(dim(data2())[1] - 11.5, dim(data2())[1] - 0.5)
               }
               in.d <- input.data
               xx <- matrix(paste(names(in.d), ": ", t(in.d), sep = ""), ncol = dim(in.d)[1])
               Covariates <- apply(xx, 2, paste, collapse = "<br />")
               p <- ggplot(data = dat2, aes(x = Prediction, y = counter - 1, text = Covariates,
               label = Prediction, label2 = Lower.bound, label3=Upper.bound)) +
               geom_point(size = 2, colour = coll[dat2$count], shape = 15) +
               ylim(yli[1], yli[2]) + coord_cartesian(xlim = lim) +
               labs(title = "95% Confidence Interval for Response",
               x = "Probability", y = "") + theme_bw() +
               theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), text = element_text(face = "bold", size = 10))
               if (is.numeric(dat2$Upper.bound)){
               p <- p + geom_errorbarh(xmax = dat2$Upper.bound, xmin = dat2$Lower.bound,
               size = 1.45, height = 0.4, colour = coll[dat2$count])
               } else{
               message("Confidence interval is not available as there is no standard errors available by 'lrm' ")
               }
               gp <- ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("text", "label", "label2", "label3"))
               gp$elementId <- NULL
               gp
})

output$data.pred <- renderPrint({
  if (input$add > 0) {
               if (nrow(data2()) > 0) {
               if (dim(input.data)[2] == 1) {
               in.d <- data.frame(input.data)
               names(in.d) <- names(terms)[2]
               data.p <- cbind(in.d, data2()[1:3])
               }
               if (dim(input.data)[2] > 1) {
               data.p <- cbind(input.data, data2()[1:3])
               }}
               stargazer(data.p, summary = FALSE, type = "text")
}
})

output$summary <- renderPrint({
print(model)
})
}


----------
**global.R**

library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(stargazer)
library(compare)
library(prediction)
library(rms)


load('data.RData')
source('functions.R')
t.dist <- datadist(data)
options(datadist = 't.dist')
m.summary <- 'raw'
covariate <- 'numeric'
clevel <- 0.95
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should post the minimal code to reproduce the issue and include dummy data. Don't  post your entire project, : most of your code is working as expected, it's noise for peoplle who would want to help you.

Comment: thanks for that! its that better? i'm a total newbie here :/

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure which type of shiny widget (or labels) you mean, but I have some comments.

Firstly, you need to make sure defining your variables' class correctly (e.g. as factors, numeric, ...), for example, by adding the following code before fitting your model:

```
> data$y <- as.factor(data$y)
```

This is especially important for factors so it gets factor levels. For numerical variables, you can get a shiny slider (by default) or a numeric input (using covariate = c("numeric")).

The labels for widgets are the same as the variable names. So the easiest way to adjust them is by changing the variable names as you like before fitting your model:

```
> names(data)
[1] "x" "y" "z"
> names(data)[2] <- 'ylabel'
> names(data)
[1] "x" "ylabel" "z"
> model <- lrm(x ~ ylabel + z, data = data)
```

Alternatively, the labels can be changed by adjusting the 'preds' object in the 'data.RData'. For example, you can use the following code to change labels:

```
> names(preds)
[1] "y" "z"         
> names(preds)[1] <- 'labelled y'
> names(preds)
[1] "labelled y" "z"         
> save.image(file = "data.RData")
```